# Storage not working properly in vuex axios response

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Whenever i dispatch data to vuex storage using axios response, for eg.

```
** Sidebar.vue **
  created(){
    this.getRoles();
  },
  methods: {
    getRoles(){
      var _this = this
      var roles = null
      this.$http.get('/api/userroles/userroles').then(function(response){
        // Passing data to vuex within response
        _this.$store.dispatch('setUserRoles', response.data.data)
      }
    }
    check_role(){

    }
  }
```

and When i console in sidebar like  **console.log(this.$store.state.userStore.roles)** it have value, but when i console in dashboard it return null and when i see vuex chrome extension it contains value (provided image below), but in dashboard it return null

```
eg in dashboard 

** dashboard.vue **
created(){
  console.log(this.$store.state.userStore.roles)
  // null
},
```

[image]

Now when i dispatch to vuex outside the axios response it works perfectly and gives value in dashboard but its throw error like Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers. for eg.

```
created(){
  this.getRoles();
},
methods: {
  getRoles(){
    var _this = this
    var roles = null
    this.$http.get('/api/userroles/userroles').then(function(response){
      _this.roles_data = response.data.data
    }
    _this.$store.dispatch('setUserRoles', _this.roles_data)
  }
}
```

eg in dashboard it give value if i use dispatch outside axios

```
** dashboard.vue **
created(){
  console.log(this.$store.state.userStore.roles)
  // (25) [{…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
},
```

Am i missing something???

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
created () {
  this.getRoles()
},

methods: {
  getRoles () {
    this.$http
      .get('/api/userroles/userroles')
      .then(({data: {data}}) => {
        this.$store.dispatch('setUserRoles', data)
      })
  }
}
```

And do not try to console roles in created method. Because it can't work, axios is async, you will console state before data arrives. If, console it in axios callback too:

```
created () {
  this.getRoles()
},

methods: {
  getRoles () {
    this.$http
      .get('/api/userroles/userroles')
      .then(({data: {data}}) => {
        this.$store.dispatch('setUserRoles', data)
        // here, not in created method
        console.log(this.$store.state.userStore.roles)
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: Still i am getting null in dashboard.vue

Comment: And console.log in axios callback works as expected?

Comment: Yes. Its showing the result. when i pass response in vmodel and then dispatch vmodel to vuex its not working. but when i pass in a variable outside axios it works perfectly but throws error like **"Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."**

Comment: Then, everything works as expected. You can't console these values in dashboard.vue in created method.

Comment: Then how can i get roles access in dashboard. i dont want to trigger api every time when page loads.

Comment: There is many ways to achieve it. In short, do it immediately after successful login as part of login process.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to console store.state.userStore.roles before api call is made. Avoid accessing store value in created()